# C: error: expected ')' before ';' token

Tags: c

This seems like the simplest code, but I don't know why it won't compile:

```
    switch(choice) {
        case 0:
            printf("%d", LOOP_LIMIT); /* this line gives the error */
            break;
        case 1:
```

when I comment out the line it compiles fine

Comment: Where/How is `LOOP_LIMIT` defined?

Comment: what _is_ LOOP_LIMIT?

Comment: Following the guidelines here would help everyone answer your query: http://sscce.org/

Comment: is LOOP_LIMIT a macro ? if then, how it is defined ?

Comment: you may at least consider providing *what* errors you got?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your code has something like this:

```
#define LOOP_LIMIT 10;
                     ^
                    Remove this semicolon.
```